# Permission denied if request.auth != null is only rule when creating documents in onComplete of mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

If I have the following rule in my Security Rules (the only rule):

```
match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

and I do the following:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(activity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                        //initial database setup
                        final WriteBatch adminSetupBatch = mDbase.batch();

                        //create adminSUsersGroup and add documentID value as a field in document
                        DocumentReference adminGroupRef = mDbase.collection("adminUserGroups").document();

                        Map<String, Object> adminGroup = new HashMap<>();
                        adminGroup.put("adminID", task.getResult().getUser().getUid());
                        adminGroup.put("age", -1);
                        adminSetupBatch.set(adminGroupRef, adminGroup);

                        //Commit the batch
                        adminSetupBatch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                               Log.d(TAG, "Admin setup batch write completed");
                              Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);
                              activity.startActivity(intent);
                              Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getContext(), MyApplication.getContext().getString(R.string.alert_adminAccountCreated),
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         }
                            else {
                             Log.d(TAG, "Error: completing Admin setup batch write", task.getException());
                             Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getContext(), task.getException().getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

             });

                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getContext(), task.getException().getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

If the createUserWithEmailAndPassword() method is successful, then create our default document(s) etc.

But for some reason I'm getting a permission denied message and no documents are created.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note: I wanted to do the initial document setup from the client rather than a cloud function because of the potential for cold starts, which would mean that if the admin creates their account, and are logged in they might be waiting for any initial data to appear, and that is not good usability.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, nevermind I think I solved this issue.  First, I was using:

```
if isSignedIn();
```

in my production code security rules which calls the following function:

```
function isSignedIn() {
   return request.auth != null;
}
```

Since I was testing and going back and forth between different rules, I had apparently forgot to also add the calling function.  So, in essence, the rule was always failing.

Answer (score 0):

try only change your permission in firebase  to

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed.  Thanks for the response.  The issue I was having was specifically when I was adding request.auth != null.  However, I had forgot to include it in my function call that I was using for testing, so that is why it was failing.